# Integromat - Save Google Doc to Airtable Attachment Field

Tags: google-docs, airtable, make.com, integromat-apps

I am trying to use Integromat to save a Google Doc to an Airtable attachment field. The problem is that the Airtable "Update a Record" module expects a "File URL" value which I am unsure how to get.

I tried choose the "Export Links: Application PDF" to the "File URL" value which does work but when I try to open/download the file saved to the Airtable attachment field, it just sends me to Google Docs sign in to Google Docs.

I tried using the Integromat Google Docs module called "Download a Document" and then save this downloaded document to the Airtable attachment field but it is expecting the URL of the file and the "Download a Document" module only returns the actual data and the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add a Google Drive "Get a Shareable Link" module after the Google Docs module to make the link "Type: Anyone". Doing this made the file downloadable to anyone without having to sign to Google.